# How to get adb logs via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

How to get adb logs via bluetooth?

need to connect an android device to my laptop to get the adb logs, but through usb cable its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you don't need Bluetooth to do so, you can get ADB logs via Wi-Fi.

The steps:

1. Connect your device to your laptop via USB (yes, you've read right, if your USB cable is not working, you can use an alternative USB cable temporarily or borrow one from your friends).
2. Type `adb tcpip 5555` in the terminal
3. Type `adb connect XXX.XXX.X.X` (the X's represent the local IP address of your mobile device, if you don't know your device's IP, go to Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced).
4. You can disconnect your device from your laptop and now you can debug your apps wirelessly.

If you really need Bluetooth to use ADB. Bad news! That's not even possible.